# How to upload blackberry application with System module?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I am working in the blackberry application which have system module as well. So would you please guide me how to upload the application with system module? And how to prepare build for client to review as well?

Looking forward for your response.

Thanks,

Devang

Comment: have you seen this page? https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberryworld/faq/

Comment: I checked but not found for what we have to do when application has system module..

Comment: ask your question on official BB dev. forum. Here is the forum section dedicated to BB App World: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/bd-p/appworld_dev